# Repository Rest Resource can't embed self-referencing object

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have two entities, a *Store* and a *ProductCategory*, that I persist and would like to retrieve from a *JpaRepository* annotated with *@RepositoryRestResource*. Stores have a collection of product categories, and product categories have a parent/child relationship with themselves. Furthermore, I'd like to embed the product categories hierarchy when a GET request is made to the Store's REST repository.

The entities look as follows:

Store:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="categories", callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude="categories", callSuper = true)
public class Store extends BaseEntity {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProductCategory.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "store")
    @Getter
    private List<ProductCategory> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setCategories(List<ProductCategory> categories) {
        for (ProductCategory category : categories) {
            if (category.getStore() == null || !category.getStore().equals(this)) {
                category.setStore(this);
            }
        }
        this.categories = categories;

    }

}
```

ProductCategory.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"store", "children", "parent"}, callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude={"store", "children", "parent"}, callSuper = true)
public class ProductCategory extends BaseEntity {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="store_id", nullable = true)
    @Getter
    @JsonIgnore
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private Store store;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent", nullable = true)
    @Getter
    @JsonIgnore
    @RestResource(exported = false, path = "parent")
    private ProductCategory parent;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProductCategory.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
    @Getter
    @RestResource(rel = "children", path = "children")
    private List<ProductCategory> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setStore(Store store) {
        this.store = store;
        if(!store.getCategories().contains(this)) {
            store.getCategories().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void setParent(ProductCategory parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        if(!parent.getChildren().contains(this)) {
            parent.getChildren().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void setChildren(List<ProductCategory> children) {
        for(ProductCategory child : children) {
            if(child.getParent() == null || !child.getParent().equals(this)) {
                child.setParent(this);
            }
        }
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

*BaseEntity* provides a unique identifier for the other entities. Each entity has their own repository:

StoreRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "store", path = "store")
public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Store, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Store> {

    Store findById(@Param("id") Long id);
    Optional<Store> findFirstByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

ProductCategoryRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "productCategory", path = "productCategory", exported = false)
public interface ProductCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductCategory, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ProductCategory> {    
    ProductCategory findById(@Param("id") Long id);
    List<ProductCategory> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

The result I'd like to receive as JSON after querying for a particular store would look like:

```
{
   id: 0,
   name: 'Pet Store',
   categories: [
       {
          id: 0,
          name: 'Mammal', 
          children: [
             {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Dog',
                children: [
                    {
                       id: 4,
                       name: 'Shiba',
                       children: []
                    },
                    {
                       id: 5,
                       name: 'Husky',
                       children: []
                    }
                ]
             },
             {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Cat',
                children: []
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Bird',
          children: []
       }
    ]
}
```

HATEOS relationships were removed for brevity. While the objects are created and read from the database just fine, when an attempt is made to retrieve a store through a GET request against the REST resource the following error is produced:

> restGetStoreProductsEmbedded(com.synthapp.embeddedproject.com.repo.StoreRepositoryTest): Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"])

I have attempted to resolve this through the following methods:

- Not exporting the ProductCategory repo
- Removing the *ProductCategoryRespository* entirely for automatic serialization instead of using *exported = false*. It really isn't required that I be able to issue database save requests to this repository, but would be nice,
- Removing the bi-directional relationships. The GitHub I reference at the end of this posting includes this example.
- Using *@JsonManagedReference* and *@JsonBackReference* instead of *@JsonIgnore*, and with *@JsonIgnore*
- A projection on the Store repository that includes the categories
  relationship. This doesn't produce an error, but it also doesn't
  provided the entire hierarchy
- Removing the "exported = false" from the ProductCategory repo and applying an InlineChildren projection to the ProductCategory repository. A GET against the api/productCategory?projection=inlineChildren endpoint causes an error about multiple association links with same relationship "children".
- An InlineChildren projection on the ProductCategory as above, but without the bi-directional relationships. This doesn't error, but it also only produces the first two tiers of the ProductCategory hierarchy.

A project implementing this example with an in memory database can be found at my [GitHub](https://github.com/mkandefer/mikes-sandbox)

Comment: I suggest to remove `store` and `parent` from `ProductCategory`. These are not only bi-directional relationships, but infinite recursive ones. Also note that `Store` contains a list of **ALL** categories. You won't get the nice tree you want, but lots of trees.

Comment: This was done and still causes the error. See the ProductCategoryNotBiDirectional class in the referenced GitHub project. Store does not create a list of all categories as not all category entities have a populated  back reference to stores, only those that are at the top of the hierarchy (e.g., "Dog" has a store relationship populated with "Pet Store", but "Shiba" and "Husky" do not). The object is retrieved fine from the database, it's only Json serialization that causes a problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, you get the exact same error without bi-directional relationships?

Comment: I'm having very similar issues to this, have you made any progress on solving your problems?

Comment: Not within the Rest repo. I ended up creating a controller that converted my object into one serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a projection for the `ProductCategory` and leave the `Store` out.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts

Be sure to also read the part on excerpts, this can be very helpful.

I create controllers that use the `PersistenEntityResourceAssembler` (since you don't want you're entities to be exposed but you want to return resources) and this will apply the projection to the resource(s) automatically without having to pass it in the url - but only if it's defined through excerpt on the repository.

Comment: I have also tried a projection on the StoreRepository that provides the categories relationship, but that only serializes one level into the hierarchy. I have not tried a projection on the ProductCategory repository itself.  

I haven't used PersistenEntityResourceAssembler before, does it automatically apply projections on any request to the resource or only when you do a listing (e.g., GET api/productCategory)?

Comment: An InlineChildren projection on the ProductCategory entities did not prevent the error. An InlineChildren projection on the ProductCategoryNotBiDirectional entities does prevent the error, but doesn't automatically embed further than one level deep in the hierarchy. I have not yet attempted a PersistenEntityResourceAssembler.

Comment: Projections are only applied to custom operations (don't forget you have to define it on your repository with excerptProjection).

If you want to apply the projection to standard operations you have to
1) add the projection parameter to the url `url?projection=<projectionname>`
OR
2) create a controller that uses the PersistentEntityResourceAssembler (override the repository get with a controller get).

You can just add the PersistentEntityResourceAssembler as an argument on your method, the assembler will be created for you. Then call toResource on the assembler.

Comment: Yep. I've worked with projections and excerpting before. I tried #1 and those results are now added to my question.  I haven't tried #2, but I wonder if #1 isn't working would #2 introduce anything to help?